# Amazon cloud drive integration with android

Tags: java, android, amazon-clouddrive

is there SDK or sample code available to integrate [Amazon cloud drive](https://www.amazon.com/ap/signin?_encoding=UTF8&openid.assoc_handle=amzn_clouddrive_us&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.pape=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fextensions%2Fpape%2F1.0&openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2Fclouddrive%2F%3F_encoding%3DUTF8%26action%3Dsign-out%26associationHandle%3Damzn_clouddrive_us%26pageId%3Dclouddrive_authportal_us%26path%3D%252Fclouddrive%252F%26ref_%3Dpd_irl_gw_r%26signIn%3D1%26useAuthPortal%3Dtrue%26useRedirectOnSuccess%3D1&pageId=clouddrive_authportal_us) with Android application.
basically i am going to develop an application with uses cloud drive for storage.
i have username and password for that storage drive.

Comment: Looks like they haven't released one that I can see.  However, did bump into this http://code.google.com/p/pyamazonclouddrive/ but looks like it might not comply with their Ts&Cs.

Comment: Perhaps you could use Amazon S3, which might be what Amazon is using for cloud drive under the covers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Now exists a SDK :
https://developer.amazon.com/public/apis/experience/cloud-drive/content/sdk-android

May be this answer will be useful for someone.